# Is there an elegant way to save and restore View state in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

Writting custom views that keep their state across configuration changes in Android is  verbose, look at the amount of boilerplate code for saving the state of just one field:

```
private class SavedState : BaseSavedState {
        var amount: Int = 0

        constructor(parcel: Parcel) : super(parcel) {
            amount = parcel.readInt()
        }

        constructor (parcelable: Parcelable?) : super(parcelable)

        override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            super.writeToParcel(parcel, flags)
            parcel.writeInt(amount)
        }

        companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> {
            override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): SavedState {
                return SavedState(parcel)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<SavedState?> {
                return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
    }
```

Android Extensions plugin provides the `@Parcelize` annotation that one can use to autogenerate implementations of `Parcelable`, but in the case of custom views we have to extend from `BaseSavedState` not directly from `Parcelable`.

So, having something like this does not compile:

```
@Parcelize
data class SavedState(val isLoading: Boolean = false): BaseSavedState()
```

I am wondering if there's a less verbose way of handling state restoration in a custom view. Would appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: "but in the case of custom views we have to extend from BaseSavedState not directly from Parcelable" -- `Parcelable` is an interface. You don't extend from it; you implement it. "having something like this does not compile" -- try replacing `BaseSavedState()` with `BaseSavedState(), Parcelable`. It's possible that `@Parcelize` will still have issues here, but in principle it should be OK.

Comment: That won't work either because `BaseSavedState(parcel)` is actually expecting an argument of type `Parcel`.

Comment: Oh, right. If you have a lot of state, you could still put that state in a `data` class with `@Parcelize` if you wanted. Then, your custom `SavedState` would be pretty much what you have in your first snippet, replacing `writeInt()` and `readInt()` with `writeParcelable()` and `readParcelable()` to write/read your `data` class instance.

Comment: Not exactly the kind of solution I was looking for, but your idea is still a better approach in the case of multiple fields in the state. Thank you.

Comment: In principle, somebody could create a `@Parcelize` equivalent for view states -- I have not looked to see if anyone has done that.

Answer (score 14):

writing a `SaveState` class is one way to do this that packs all the data that needs to be saved into one class. another way is to just override `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` and put your arguments in a bundle. this avoids the boilerplate you mentioned. if you have several arguments just use  data class with `@Parcelize` annotation and save that class using `bundle.putParcelable`.(instead of the amount in this example). also don't forget to set `isSaveEnabled` to true.

```
init { isSaveEnabled = true }

...

override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable {
   val bundle = Bundle()
   bundle.putInt("amount", amount)
   bundle.putParcelable("superState", super.onSaveInstanceState())
   return bundle
}
```

```
override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable) {
 var viewState = state
 if (viewState is Bundle) {
   amount = viewState.getInt("amount", 0)
   viewState = viewState.getParcelable("superState")
 }
 super.onRestoreInstanceState(viewState)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`@Parcelize` annotation can still be used because the base class that we have to extend `BaseSavedState` implements `Parcelable`. Here is an example where I needed to save some duration in a custom view that I defined.

```
@Parcelize
internal class SavedState(state: Parcelable?, val duration: Long) : BaseSavedState(state)
```

As you can see, we can use the annotation to only define the state and the fields that we want to save. Once we have the state ready, we can save/restore it like this:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable {
    val parcel = super.onSaveInstanceState()
    return SavedState(parcel, currentDuration.timeInMillis)
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
    if (state !is SavedState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
        return
    }

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state.superState)
    setDurationInMillis(state.duration)
}
```

Starting from this implementation, you could add the `Parcelable` argument for the state class and pass it to the base class. With this, everything should work properly.

Comment: The non-class field `state` in the custom `SavedState` class will now throw a compile-time exception stating that it _has_ to be declared as a class-field. However, attempting to declare it as a variable would say that doing so is not needed. What should be done about this?

Comment: I'm not sure that I get your point. Could you please elaborate more on this (with some code included)?

Comment: Your current code as-is would cause Kotlin to throw an error saying that it has to be declared with a `val`/`var` keyword, but adding said keyword would show that it's not necessary (i.e. the `val`/`var` keyword is greyed out) as it's only used as a constructor argument for `BaseSavedState`.

Comment: The code worked and I don't see any reason why it would break now. I would guess that there is something else that breaks it, especially since I don't recall ever seeing the kind of compile error you are describing. Could you add the full error and maybe the implementation of your view?

Answer (score 0):

Building off @Mohsen's answer, here's the most elegant Kotlin solution I could immediately come up with:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable = bundleOf(
    "amount" to amount,
    "superState" to super.onSaveInstanceState()
)

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable) = super.onRestoreInstanceState(
    if (state is Bundle) {
        amount = state.getInt("amount", 0)
        state.getParcelable("superState")
    } else {
        amount = 0
        state
    }
)
```